# Environment variable for ip address

Tags: debian, ubuntu, networking, environment-variables, ip

I see somewhere people use:

```
IF_ADDRESS="$(echo "$IP4_ADDRESS_0" | cut -d'/' -f1)"
```

to get the IP address in a network configuration script. In my system, I create a script under the directory `/etc/network/if-up.d/` and test with:

```
echo "$IP4_ADDRESS_0" >> /tmp/test.log
```

but get nothing with this variable. What's wrong?

My `/etc/network/interfaces` is like this:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

My final purpose is to set up the IP routing policy with a script like [this](https://serverfault.com/a/487962/61493).

Answer (score 2):

`$IP4_ADDRESS_0` is a variable, so it's likely not set. You can see it's value with this command:

```
$ echo "$IP4_ADDRESS_0"
```

If it's blank you'll see this:

```
$ echo "$IP4_ADDRESS_0"

$
```

You could use this command instead:

```
$ ifconfig eth0 | grep 'inet addr:' | cut -d: -f2 | awk '{ print $1}'
192.168.1.27
```

Comment: Yes, it works. So $IP4_ADDRESS_0 is not a predefined variable like the $IFACE or $METHOD, right?

Comment: @platinor - I don't think so. If you use the command `grep IP4 /etc/network/if-up.d/*` you don't find any examples of it being used there.

Comment: The variable probably comes from _some kind of dispatcher script_ relating to something called "NetworkManager" on Linux. I'm not a Linux guy, but that's what came up when searching.